# Keep focus on another control while selecting items in a ListBox

Tags: wpf, focus, listboxitem

I have TextBox which should always be in focus.
At the same time I have as list box.
When user clicks on certain item in this listobox the item clicked gets focus.

I tried to set **Focusable="false"** for each ListBoxItem in my ListBox but in this case no item can be selected.
I found following code using dotPeek:

```
private void HandleMouseButtonDown(MouseButton mouseButton)
{
  if (!Selector.UiGetIsSelectable((DependencyObject) this) || !this.Focus())
    return;
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to solve my problem?

Comment: Do you want to select item in listbox, but not highlight that item in blue color ?

Comment: I want to be able to select listbox item by mouse but without loosing focus on my textbox.

Comment: You can set focus on textbox again in listbox's SelectionChanged event.

Comment: Well, yes, it will work but it's a pretty ugly solution. TextBox and ListBox are located in different user controls so do not know anything about each other. I'd rather prefer to implement my own listbox ans ListBoxItem than use such aproach.

Comment: Then you can do one thing. You have to find that textbox by parent/child relation. I don't know is it possible or not. If possible then we can find it as like in web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle PreviewMouseDown on the ListBoxItems and mark the event as Handled which will stop the focus being transferred.

You can set `e.Handled = true` because MouseButtonEventArgs is a [RoutedEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx).

This demo works to keep focus on the TextBox:

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350"
        Width="525">
    <StackPanel FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=textBox}">
        <TextBox  x:Name="textBox" />
        <ListBox x:Name="listBox">
            <ListBoxItem PreviewMouseDown="ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseDown">1</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem PreviewMouseDown="ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseDown">2</ListBoxItem>
            <ListBoxItem PreviewMouseDown="ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseDown">3</ListBoxItem>
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = sender as ListBoxItem;
            if (item == null) return;
            listBox.SelectedItem = item;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```